# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An invalid argument was supplied'

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An invalid argument was supplied'

```
_socket.Connect(Dns.GetHostAddresses("vcap.me"), 1832);
```

Full Code:

```
namespace App.Root.Core.Network.Sockets
{
    class SocketHandler
    {
        private readonly Socket _socket;
        private readonly Timer _timer;

        public SocketHandler()
        {
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _timer = new Timer(OnTick, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }

        private void Connect()
        {
            if (IsConnected())
            {
                return;
            }

            _socket.Connect(Dns.GetHostAddresses("vcap.me"), 1832);
        }

        private bool IsConnected()
        {
            return !((_socket.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead) && (_socket.Available == 0)) || !_socket.Connected);
        }

        private void OnTick(object obj)
        {
            if (!IsConnected())
            {
                CoreUtilities.LogToConsole("Connecting to the server...");
                Connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All I do is initialize the SocketHandler constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the Timer was creating a seperate thread, and it was busy processing the first Thread hence why it couldn't connect inside the second thread.